# VB.Net method to print all available reports with a single button click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have created a windows form with a crystal reports viewer, a combo box to select a report to view, and a button that I would like to (Print All Reports). The print button in the viewers toolbar will print the report currently being viewed. I want the button in my application to print all the reports without viewing them.

I have following code, but it throws an exception of type 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException' occurred in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
Additional information: Load report failed.

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms


Public Class frmReport

Private Sub frmReport_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub cboReport_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboReport.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim rptCustomer As New Customer
    Dim rptEmployee As New Employee

    Select Case cboReport.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptCustomer
        Case 1
            Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptEmployee

    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub btnPrintReports_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrintReports.Click

    Dim rptCustomer As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    Dim rptEmployee As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

    rptCustomer.Load("Customer.rpt")
    rptEmployee.Load("Employee.rpt")

    rptCustomer.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
    rptEmployee.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)

End Sub


End Class
```

I have searched and failed to find a solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument`'s [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method you need to specify a path and a filename.

Also, have you granted `NETWORK SERVICE` permissions on `Windows\Temp`?

Comment: The reports are within the project. (same directory) and the filenames are in the call. ie; Customer.rpt & Employee.rpt. Tell me about NETWORK SERVICE permissions on Windows\Temp...